# Beginner in Apache ServiceMix

Tags: java, apache, apache-servicemix

**Hello everyone,**
I started few days ago Apache ServiceMix and i cant find any good tutorial.
I have a project in java and now i want to run it in ServiceMix and i dont know how to do it?
I want to know too how to connect two services, first service start and another take somethink from this first?
Please help me it is very important to me.
My java project are in REST or SOAP and they are very easy to write: HelloWorld or take values and display result.

I m using: Apache ServiceMix 5.1.2, Java 8, 1.8 JDK, maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good Tutorial i found is [ServiceMix Tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072293/soa/servicemix-as-an-enterprise-service-bus.html)

Here are 2 examples, one JBI and one OSGI, that you can use to start you first SOAP web-service and deploy it in ServiceMix.

JBI: http://cis.ait.asia/course_offerings/49/servicemix_tutorial_4

I actually made the above example work and then I switched from ant to maven. If you try it and encounter any kind of problems I would be happy to help you. Please keep in mind that JBI is kind of obsolete.

OSGI: http://www.jakubkorab.net/2012/02/developing-web-services-in-servicemix.html

Here you will find 3 examples, one plain CXF and two with Apache Camel. The packaging is OSGI instead of JBI.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but in Apache ServiceMix i have folder examples and i dont know why they dont running well, they dont work. Its hard topic to me, hard to learn and hard to start working. Please more help. Your Answer is useful to me but its not enough.

Comment: JBI link - example cant download
OSGI - need Jboss Fuse ... it isnt free :(

Comment: do not use JBI that is dead!

Comment: And start learn Apache Camel first, then learn about SMX later. SMX is just the container to run Camel. And check out Apache Karaf instead of ServiceMix as there is more docs about Karaf than SMX (eg as a container)

Comment: JBoss Fuse has both community and enterprise product - community is http://fabric8.io/ which is 100% FOSS and free to use. JBoss Fuse requires a subscription to use in production - but free to use for trial and development